# Was the North Korean leader, Kim Il-Sung, an imposter?

Tags: history, north-korea

Some claim the founder of North Korea, [Kim Il-Sung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Il-sung), was an imposter who adopted the name of another leader.

Article from [globalsecurity](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/world/dprk/kim-il-sung.htm)

> South Korea claims that the present-day ruler of North Korea is an
>   imposter who stole the name of a revered patriot.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Il-sung):

> There is much controversy about Kim's political career before the
>   founding of North Korea, with some sources indicating he was an
>   imposter. Several sources indicate that the Kim Il-sung name had
>   previously been used by a prominent early leader of the Korean
>   resistance, Kim Kyung-cheon (김경천).[12][page needed]

There appear to be two historical figures whom both changed their birth names to Kim Il-Sung: the Kim Kyung-cheon (Korean independence activist) and Kim Sŏng-ju (the founder of North Korea, who this question is about). Admittedly both were politically active in Korea and had the same name, but this doesn't mean one stole the others identity. Can anyone identify some events where Kim Song-ju tried to make people believe he was Kim Kyung-cheon or take credit for his work?

Comment: The bounty asks "What purported occurrences happened that make people claim Kim Il-Sung was an imposter, even unverified ones?" That's out-of-scope. Skeptics.SE isn't about reporting rumours; it is about reporting evidence-based conclusions.

Comment: @Oddthinking the first part of verifying a claim is to understand the claim being made.

Comment: Yup, but that should involve making a comment - or even better, editing the question - to show the notable claim. It isn't an answer.

Comment: Is there anyone claiming that Kim Il-Sung was not an outsider installed by the Soviets?